# OnClick Event JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having a few issues getting a jquery to perform an onclick event.

I am able to get it working by using a simple Click ME

Though this isn't the best practice.

I have created a jsfiddle to better explain what I am trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/UuSWm/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/UuSWm/11/

You code was practically correct (you've missed the `#` on `#p1`).

I've also removed the `onLoad` event option on the jsfiddle to make the test work.